# Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, Network Manager Hotspot, 'No Internet connection'

Tags: networking, network-manager, iptables, 20.04, ap-hotspot

After upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I noticed Hotspot feature seemed working, and phones were able to connect by wifi, but then they reported `No internet connection`

After checking network-manager logs, it looks like when the `Hotspot` feature is enabled/disabled, it tries to configure `iptables`. If you check the logs:

```
sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
```

you can see here, it is trying to use iptables throught `/sbin/iptables` path, but it's not the real installation path of it:

```
NetworkManager[1328]: <warn>  [1588096735.3274] Error executing command: Failed to execute child process “/sbin/iptables” (No such file or directory)
```

As it is not able to configure the redirections, it won't bridge the connetions to/from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a symbolic link in that path, pointing to the real binary will do the trick:

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/iptables /sbin/iptables
```

And then, it doesn't print those warnings, and Hotspot is working again.